# Regex add spaces in a math expression (cab+++=1+2+3 -> cab++ += 1 + 2 + 3)

Tags: regex, perl

I have this regex (which almost work):

```
 s/(?<!\+|-| )(\+|-)(?!=|\+|-| )/ $1 /g;
```

https://regex101.com/r/oQ8qU8/2

And I want to add a space before and after each `+` and `-` char. Here's the test string:

```
 cab+=1+2+3+deb++-5+-5;
```

The output should be:

```
 cab += 1 + 2 + 3 + deb++ - 5 + -5;
```

I would like to treat all the C/C++ special cases such as a negative number `A=-C`->`A = -C`, an pre/post incremented variable `A++=3` -> `A++ = 3`...

Is there a good solution to use a regexp here?

Comment: This is a very difficult thing to do in general. For instance, how about `c+++++a+b+++a` meaning `c++ + ++a + b + ++a`?

Comment: @Borodin I slowly realize the complexity of my question :(

Comment: @coin, for the record, Perl parses `c+++++a+b+++a` as `( ((c++)++ + a) + b++) + a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a sub for you, since those regular expressions kept growing and growing...

```
sub format{
        my $text = shift;
        #substitute '+'
        $text =~ s/(?<!\+)\+(?!\+|=)/ \+ /g;
        #substitute '-'        
        $text =~ s/(?<!-)-(?!-|=|>)/ - /g;
        #substitute '= , +=, -= (...)'
        $text =~ s/([\+,-,\*,\/]?=)/ $1 /g;

        #get rid of additional spaces:
        $text =~ s/  / /g;
        return $text;
}
```

Here are some results:

```
converting: foo+--bar++-3 += 3-x--+bar = ++c-*const->char++ +2
to:         foo + --bar++ - 3 += 3 - x-- + bar = ++c - *const->char++ + 2

converting: ++x->(a+b+--c) *= c++-++b/=9;
to:         ++x->(a + b + --c) *= c++ - ++b /= 9;

converting: b+c+a+d-=++*char->(--c+d);
to:         b + c + a + d- = ++*char->(--c + d);
```

Comment: Right but in this case I cannot deal with the special cases like `ted+++2+3+--i` -> `ted++ + 2 + 3 + --i`

Comment: Indeed. Your example above is a bit confusing tbh. How does 'ted-8' become 'ted++ - 8' ? Same with 'foo+bar' => 'foo + --bar'?